# Convert one response object to another object(pojo) in Spring webflux flux responce without subscribing it

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to consume one rest api which returns response in FLUX. 
My target is to consume rest api and process flux response object (Convert one response object-1 to another object-2(pojo) in Spring 5 webflux ) and return object-2 with response to caller application without subscribing it.

Comment: Afraid this is much too vague at present. Can you post a [mcve] of the problem you're having? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using webclient as rest client that allows you to get Flux as response and then use map to convert the object to any other type and the use webclient again to submit the new response.
For example:

```
FLux<Foo> response = webClient.get()
            .uri("/foo")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(GithubRepo.class);
Flux<Bar> converted = response.map(response -> convertToBar(response));

webClient.post()
            .uri("/bar")
            .body(converted, Bar.class)
            .retrieve();
```

Here you have a complete tutorial on how to use webclient.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient